# Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in a Silex Application

Tags: namespaces, autoload, silex, php

I moved my website from local to a hosting, and something happened to me. I include this config file into my `index.php` (it's the first thing I do):

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';

// some other stuff

$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = true;

$defaultLocale = 'en';

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => array(
                            __DIR__.'/../views', 
                            __DIR__.'/../views/backend', 
                            __DIR__.'/../views/layouts',
                            __DIR__.'/../views/components',
                            __DIR__.'/../views/backend/components', 
                        ),
));
$app->register(new Nicl\Silex\MarkdownServiceProvider());
```

But the website complains this way:

> **Warning**: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in
>   /public_html/_inc/config.php on line 7
>
> **Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in
>   /public_html/_inc/config.php on line 7

Basically, line 7 is `$app = new Silex\Application();`. I'm using Silex and the server is running PHP 5.2. The vendor folder (which contains all the framework and third parties stuff) is in root (`/`)

I was wondering it had some problems with autoload, but I don't find what could exactly be or how to test it. Do you find anything strange? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe I had to try harder, but I already searched for this. However _almost_ everybody was showing unrelated solutions.

Comment: Yes, I didn't say it's super-easy. Your question is fine btw. Also Florent is straight to the point. We should keep it for further reference.

Comment: great to hear that. I added the [namespaces] tag, for the sake of the answer.

Comment: I just added the php-errors tag as well. We also try to improve the "error message" - to -> "solution" situation with this reference: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456 - probably this is of help from time to time.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/intro.html), Silex requires **PHP 5.3** to provide namespace support.
Try to migrate your server to PHP 5.3 in order to get rid of this error.

> Silex is a PHP microframework for PHP 5.3.

Comment: Oh my... I just skipped that. I don't know why, but I always get lost when looking at Silex docs. Thanks!